# Images not loading properly

Tags: javascript, html, ios, canvas

I am developing an HTML and js app that will run on IOS devices. In this app I am using lots of images and using src to set the path of these images inside a function. After this function completes i am calling another function where I am drawing a canvas, the problem is that all these images are not loading properly, some of the images's width remains 0. How can I ensure that all the images are getting loaded properly before i call the next function.

Thanks

Comment: We need to see your relevant code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 canvas drawImage not working on first click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796300/html5-canvas-drawimage-not-working-on-first-click)

Answer (score 4):

Please do more searching before you ask a question.

Waiting for the images to finish loading is easy:

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.onload = function(){
  // execute drawImage statements here
};
img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path
```

Make sure the onload event has fired for each image before trying to draw. **If you have multiple images** and don't want to make something complicated then there are libraries that do this for you, such as [pxloader](http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/).

Comment: This saved me!!! After struggling to find out what the issue was for 2 hours straight! Initially it wasn't working but I added all the code that followed image loading in the onload function. This sounds basic and I am using Js for the first time, but THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

**This will ensure all your images are loaded**

```
var images = [{src: "foo.jpg"},{...}];
var loaded = 0;
function loadImages(){
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;++i){
  var tmp = new Image;
  tmp.onload = function(){loaded++;if(loaded == images.length){nextStep();}};
  tmp.src = images[i].src;
}

function nextStep(){
  console.log("everything loaded");
}

loadImages();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the image onload event to trigger code to run when the image is fully loaded; below is an example. The code in the handler attached to image.onload runs when the image is fully loaded somewhere after I set the image.src.

```
var p = {    
    display: function(imageUrl) {
        var availableDimensions = this.getAvailableDimensions();
        $("#loadingImg").css("display", "none");
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
            canvas.style.display = "inline";
        };
        image.src = imageUrl + "&width=" + availableDimensions.width + "&height=" + availableDimensions.height + "&negative=false";
    }
}
```

Comment: well, if you can do it for one image, you surely can do it for many images, not ?